# Formating dataframe for a ggalluvial plot between 2 categorical variables?

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggalluvial

I have a dataframe with three categorical variables:

- classification1 : "1", "2", "3", "4"
- classification2 : "Low", "Med", "High"
- survival: "1" (alive), "2" (dead)

The dataframe is composed of multiples rows, one for each individual.
The 20 first rows:

```
classification1 <- c(4, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 4, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 3, 2)
classification2 <- c("Medium", "Medium", "Low", "High", "High", "Low", "Medium", "Medium", "High", "Low", "Low", "Low", "High", "High", "Medium", "Low", "Medium", "Low", "Medium", "Medium")
survival <- c(2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1)
df <- data.frame(classification1, classification2, survival)
```

I want to use `ggalluvial`with `ggplot2` to build an alluvial plot like this, but I can't figure how!

[image: alluvial plot]

The following code return an error (
`Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : objet 'Freq' introuvable`
) because I can't figure out what is "Freq":

```
ggplot(data = df, aes(axis1 = classification1, axis2 = classification2, y = Freq)) +
  scale_x_discrete(limits = c("classification1", "classification2"), expand = c(.2, .05)) +
  geom_alluvium(aes(fill = survival)) +
  geom_stratum() +
  geom_text(stat = "stratum", aes(label = after_stat(stratum)))
```

Any clues on how to format my dataframe to fit in `ggaluvial`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could aggregate your dataset using e.g. `dplyr::count` to add a column with the frequencies:

```r
library(ggalluvial)
library(dplyr)

df <- df %>% 
  count(classification1, classification2, survival, name = "Freq")

ggplot(data = df, aes(axis1 = classification1, axis2 = classification2, y = Freq)) +
  scale_x_discrete(limits = c("classification1", "classification2"), expand = c(.2, .05)) +
  geom_alluvium(aes(fill = factor(survival))) +
  geom_stratum() +
  geom_text(stat = "stratum", aes(label = after_stat(stratum)))
```

[image]