# ggalluvial Warning messages: 1: Computation failed in `stat_stratum()` Caused by error in `default_missing()`

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggalluvial

I am trying to reproduce the solution given in this post, which includes a nice reproducible example

[Formating dataframe for a ggalluvial plot between 2 categorical variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69652461/formating-dataframe-for-a-ggalluvial-plot-between-2-categorical-variables)

However, I cant get this plot, I miss the text labels and I get different colors: [image]
it is I think because I get this message:

```
1: Computation failed in `stat_stratum()`
Caused by error in `default_missing()`:
! could not find function "default_missing" 
2: Computation failed in `stat_stratum()`
Caused by error in `default_missing()`:
! could not find function "default_missing"
```

I am using ggalluvial v0.12.03 ggplot2 v3.4.0 and R v. 4.1.2, could I fix it somehow?
because I would really like to do a similar plot with my data but I get the same error!
Thanks!

Comment: What code did you run exactly? Did you have `geom_alluvium(aes(fill = factor(survival))) +` just like the example? Because the output doesn't look like you are using a factor. Please make your question complete and reproducible by including the data and code you are running. If I copy/paste the existing code from the previous question, I get the desired output.

Comment: I dont get the text inside the plot, I still get the output as the picture I attached and the error I copied...

Comment: Seems like a reported bug https://github.com/corybrunson/ggalluvial/issues/111. Try installing at least version 0.12.05 by running `install.packages("ggalluvial")`